# Differences between start out and simply start?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In which contexts or phrases is better to use "start out" instead of just "start"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Start out](https://www.google.com/search?q=start+out+definition&rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS693US693&oq=start+out+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.2077j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is used in the same context as "beginning".

> They are **beginning** a new stage of life.

is the same as

> They are **starting out** in a new stage of life.

It can also be used as a statement of what you will do:

> I will **start out** this game as a rogue.

[Start](https://www.google.com/search?q=start+out+definition&rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS693US693&oq=start+out+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.2077j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=start+definition) is not usually much different.  It has less strength, so to speak, than "start out", but practically it's the same.

More context to the question could yield a more specific answer (such as which word choice would be best for a given situation).